# Getting Error 550 "No such user here" when sending mail to my other domain

Tags: email, cpanel, mx, smtp

I have two hosting accounts, `personaldomain.com` and `companydomain.com`. Both have User level cPanel. Whenever I try to send email from `personaldomain.com` to **any** email address on `companydomain.com`, I instantly receive a Mail Delivery System message saying:

```
Subject: **Mail delivery failed: returning message to sender**

A message that you send could not
be delivered to one or more of its
recipients. This is a permanent error.
The following address(es) failed:

theiremail@personaldomain.com
  No Such User Here
```

This only happens from `personaldomain.com` to `companydomain.com`, and not the other way. I've tried each address, and looking at the headers, it doesn't seem to be leaving my mail server:

```
Received: from ns1.usm4.siteground.biz ([my-ip-address] helo=mymailserver1.usm4.siteground.biz)
         by se8.mailspamprotection.com with esmtps (TLSv1.2:DHE-RSA-AES256-SHA:256)
         (Exim 4.85)
         (envelope-from <myemail@personaldomain.com>)
         id 1aYcMc-0003NN-Qz
         for theiremail@companydomain.com; Wed, 24 Feb 2016 10:32:37 -0600
 Received: from localhost ([127.0.0.1]:38882 helo=mymailserver.usm4.siteground.biz)
         by mymailserver1.usm4.siteground.biz with esmtpsa (TLSv1:DHE-RSA-AES256-SHA:256)
         (Exim 4.80.1)
         (envelope-from <james@duckduckloop.com>)
         id 1aYcMc-0007Zf-Lg
         for theiremail@companydomain.com; Wed, 24 Feb 2016 11:32:34 -0500
 Received: from an-ip-address ([an-ip-address]) by mysubserver.sgcpanel.com
  (Horde Framework) with HTTP; Wed, 24 Feb 2016 16:32:34 +0000
  Date: Wed, 24 Feb 2016 16:32:34 +0000
 [more content headers and filters]
 X-SpamExperts-Outgoing-Class: ham
 X-SpamExperts-Outgoing-Evidence: Combined (0.29)
 X-Recommended-Action: accept
```

I also noticed that the returned emails have a time of 4:32am when my server is 11:32am EST (sending from Webmail Horde) and my local time is 10:32am (sending from Outlook or iPhone). I don't know if that affects the authentication.

I'm able to send to `companydomain.com` from any other email address. I'm able to send to any other domain from `personaldomain.com`.

How can I figure out the source of this error, so I can fix it?

Comment: Thought I should add that I've whitelisted both domains between each other.

Answer (score 2):

A 550 error code means that your SMTP server isn't able to deliver the sent email to the user because recipient mailbox does not exist. According to me if your hosting account is running on shared environment rather than dedicated then please contact your hosting service provider and say them to check your e-mail functionality. Might be your email functionality have disabled by them for any bla bla reason.

Comment: Thing is, it works for every other domain I've tried. It's only from one specific domain to another specific domain. It is a virtual server, but I control all the MX records and spam settings, just don't know where to find the error log.

Comment: Can you you please paste some exim_mainlog. so i can assist you better.

Comment: It turns out it wasn't anything to do with the email system. I started working on another server-side project, and my personal server could not reach my work server through HTTP request, so I started digging, and apparently it's a DNS issue of some kind. I have both hosting companies working on it.

Comment: You mean CASE CLOSED :D

Answer (score 1):

This happens when u have both domain hosting configured under the same server.
the issue happens from the receiver domain only if the hosting is configured in same server but email is configured in another/remote server.
When u send a email it checks the local server for the same domain first for email address.

what you have to do is configure the route email to remote email server on the receiver hosting settings in the same server. this will resolve the issue.

Answer (score 0):

**Solution:**

1. Email Routing in cPanel.

[image: cPanel]

2. Remote Mail Exchanger.

[image: Email Routing]

*Note:* Make sure your MX and other email DNS records are on your host first.

Comment: Although they didn't answer their own question, the OP has clarified the issue in a comment on another answer.  Your answer may apply sometimes, but not in this case.